# Revoking own suggested edits

Tags: discussion, feature-request, edits, suggested-edits

I cannot seem to find any place where you can cancel an edit you have suggested to a post before it is approved.

I have just mistakenly modified the scope of a question, but missing something in an edit. This was pointed by a comment on my answer on the same question, which made me see my mistake. Sadly, this was very subtle, and two reviewers had already approved it.

How come an editor doesn't have their right to revoke a bad suggested-edit?

Comment: Also, if any admins are present, please ROLLBACK this question (http://stackoverflow.com/posts/32914530/revisions) to original state. Edit was just approved =\

Comment: Rolled back. It would actually be nice if a user could reject their own suggested edit, not sure how easy that would be with the current system.

Comment: [Here's an M.SE duplicate](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/123355/288751)

Comment: @TinyGiant - Thank you. As you can see, the selected answer says don't worry, but I tend to disagree, as the feature is one that there's no risk in implementing, only benefit, avoiding cases where reviewers interested in the badge don't review the changes in depth.

Comment: You can retract close votes.  Seems a good idea to be able to retract edits

Comment: For posterity's sake it should be noted that you *cannot* retract reopen votes cc@RichardScriven

Comment: One thing I can think of for not allowing someone to retract a suggested edit is that they get reviewed.  If you retract your edit then  all of the work that reviewers have already put in gets invalidated.

Comment: The stats on some of those reviewers are terrible http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9716990

Comment: @NathanOliver: The cynical part of me likes to think of this as a way to spite robo-reviewers. Post a shitty edit as bait, and revoke it as soon as it gets approve votes. Only downside is that it doesn't work with owner approvals since owner votes are binding.

Comment: @AndyHayden I'd like to see one or two of those reviewers given some time off from reviewing...

Answer (score 33):

If you edit a post again at any time before the edit is finally approved, you can make whatever modifications you like, and they will change the suggestion accordingly. If you know how the post should have been changed, put in the right editing and let it go.

Obviously, use this ability with discretion.

Comment: That does run into the minimum-character-limit for suggested edits. Otherwise, it might work the same as for direct edits within the grace-period. Actually, it would be interesting to test what happens when doing the same with suggested edits approved within less than five minutes...

Comment: @Deduplicator: Hmm, hadn't considered the character minimum, but you're probably right that that'd block the trivial undoing. I have actually tested grace period editing of suggestions and there's no five-minute period at all.

Comment: another issue is that once edited a post, you don't have access to the original, as SO displays your edited version to you even before it's approved. The only way to get the original is via incognito, but then you can't edit to copy the original content, because you are not logged in. A bummer.

Comment: @NitaiJ.Perez: Check the revision history.

Comment: I guess the one thing you could do is edit the question again to change the edit comment to something like "Please don't accept this suggestion, I messed up."

Comment: @TinyGiant - good call on that one. I'd actually accept it as an answer.

Comment: i was thinking of a post, where the users can post the link of suggested edits, and community can out-rightly reject it.

Comment: If I try to edit the question back to how it originally was, it won’t let me save my edit because of the character minimum limit. And if it did let me do that, it would probably display my empty edit in the revision history and show the question as recently edited. IMO, @TinyGiant’s suggestion to change your message to be “please reject” is the closest you can get. But it seems mean to give people edit rejection stats when they want to recall their edit/accidentally submitted an edit.

Comment: @Binki edit approval and rejection stats don't mean all that much unless you don't have much history, and if you don't then it really isn't going to cause you much of an inconvenience unless you regularly make edit suggestions that get rejected. Better yet, get some repz and you can start making edits that don't have to be reviewed.

Comment: I removed an being-burninated tag from a closed question. The n I read properly the instructions and saw that closed questions should not be edited, becasue the tag would be mass-deleted for them. However, if I try to "revert my edit" be placing back the tag, I can't save it , "*Nothing appears to have changed*"

Comment: This answer lacks information if you really need to redraw it, what should you do see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/381223/my-edit-should-be-retracted as example. (I pointed it to other dupe, since the answer here did not really apply). Maybe @TinyGiant's comment is answer?