# What can I do to avoid edit collisions that leave a post in a bad state?

Tags: discussion, edits, rejected-edits

Just before I left my computer yesterday, I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47895750/unwanted-looping-in-c-sharp). At the time that I viewed the question, no edits had been made to it. The question had all of the user's code as plain text so I made a quick edit to put the code in a code sample. I then entered the edit summary and clicked submit. Upon submitting, I saw that another user had made edits (which is what the question currently looks like). I didn't think anything of it, and went ahead and left my computer.

Today however, I discovered that my edit was still submitted as a suggestion and rejected, despite the other user's edit. Upon looking at my edit,[image: my edit]it appears that my suggested edit must have come a few seconds after the current edit, because it shows my edit in comparison to the current edit rather than in comparison to the original post. As you will see in the picture, this produced a rather unfortunate result. Apparently the original post contained the highlighted word and the current edit had changed it to a different word. I didn't notice this when I made the original edit, as I was only attempting to put the code in a code sample for better readability. I read [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307286/revoking-own-suggested-edits), which would suggest that if I know the correct edit, I should make it. However the correct edit had already been made. It doesn't appear that you can revoke your own suggested edits (nor did I even think to when I saw the current edits), so my question is,

**What can I do to avoid this situation in the future?**

Comment: Well... now there's coffee all over my screen. Well done.

Comment: It would almost feel legitimate to approve this suggested edit. (joking)

Comment: Title suggestion: "What can I do to avoid edit collisions that leave a post in a retarded state?"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Fix all of the problems in a post, rather than just editing a post to make one minor change and leaving other problems in a post.  Had you actually fixed all of the problems with that post (or even just some of the low hanging fruit) you wouldn't have been in this position.

Comment: In this particular example, I think that would be fine. However the same thing could have happened had I say, added an apostrophe somewhere. It would still end up with an edit that looks like there is only 1 minor change. Is there anything I can do in that situation?

Comment: @Sudsy1002 Yes, had you made an entirely different minor change, and left major problem in the question untouched, you'd still be in the same situation, that's correct.  That's why you need to make your edits substantial, and fix all of the problems in a post that you're able to, rather than just adding a missing apostrophe and skipping reviewing the rest of the question for needed edits.

Comment: I suppose what I'm trying to say is that even if I had changed that line to say "I'm sorry if this is not a good question" as apposed to leaving it alone like I did, the result would have been the same. I'm asking, how can I avoid such a result?

Comment: @Sudsy1002 And I'm giving you the answer.  You actually fix all of the problems with that post.  That whole sentence fragment is pointless, it doesn't belong in a question (it's just noise).  You should have just deleted the sentence fragment from the question (along with the other content that's irrelevant to the question).  Had you done that, you wouldn't be in this situation, as your edit would have still been a quality, useful edit even after the other user's edit.

Comment: I suppose I should spend more time reviewing the post for problems then. I'll make sure to do a better job in the future, thank you for your answer.

Comment: @Sudsy1002 Follow this answer's advice, but _don't mark it as accepted_. We still need to fix the underlying software problem (not bug, but... challenge), in addition to making quality, comprehensive edits.

Comment: @NH While I agree that there is an "underlying software problem", I believe Servy answered the question. I would say that even if I made a _perfect_ edit, the changes could still be small enough to warrant rejecting the suggested edit. However my question was "What can **I** do to avoid this situation in the future?" I believe Servy's answer tells me what **I** can do, whereas the "underlying software problem" is outside of my hands.

Comment: Is it really that obvious that the word retarded should have been changed? I would not have thought about it if I edited it.

Comment: @klutt: no, the entire phrase, if not the entire sentence should have been removed, as it is irrelevant to the actual problem.

Comment: -1 The fragment may not be necessary, but it's not a problem, either. (Yes, even using "retarded" isn't a problem. We're not the political correctness police here.) Faulting a user for leaving in a harmless sentence while making other substantive improvements is wrong.