# My edit should be retracted

Tags: support

I don't have enough reputation to undo my edit, but it should be retracted because after editing an answer I realized that it was actually a question. Is there a way to have it retracted?

https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/22452728

Comment: I'm not sure you can retract it, but I can reject it :). Nice job knowing that you should not edit NAA

Comment: The best suggestion I found is this by Tiny https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307286/revoking-own-suggested-edits#comment253979_307301