# I cannot retract my suggested edit to a tag

Tags: support, status-completed, suggested-edits, tag-wiki

Can a moderator reject my edit to a tag? I edit it and I found I cannot withdraw my operation.

Comment: Before I reject it, can you check and see if you can withdraw it from this page: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/26087661?

Comment: @CodyGray I cannot withdraw it from the page. And the pages shows "Your suggested edit is pending review."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, I have rejected [the suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/26087661).

I could not remember for sure, but it looks like the site does not currently provide a way for you to retract/withdraw your currently pending suggested edits. That might make for a good feature request.

As an alternative to having a moderator reject it, it's worth noting that you can also submit another edit to the exact same post/wiki before yours is approved/rejected, which will replace the pending edit.

Comment: I believe retracing suggested edits have several feature-requests, where this seems to be the end of the line of duplicate targets [Revoking own suggested edits](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/307286)